# E1-runtimemigration label on substrate repo is missing?

Tags: runtime-upgrade

There was the `E1-runtimemigration` label for PRs in substrate repo that needed migrations. It seems to be missing now: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pulls?q=is%3Apr%20label%3AE1-runtimemigration . I didn't find any other relevant label. Did something change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the labels were recently changed. [here](https://github.com/paritytech/labels) you can find the new labels of all 3 repos. The labels were replaced only on open PRs/issues.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has been changed to `E0-runtime_migration`

Comment: There are only 2 PRs with this label: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pulls?q=is%3Apr+label%3AE0-runtime_migration+
Does it mean that this information for older PRs is now lost?

Comment: Will ask in chat, thanks for reporting.

Comment: Yes. https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/13009 this one had a label a few days ago.